Ошибка responce[403] при попытке получить контент с сайта
Всем привет!
При попытке получить контент с сайта для парсинга (применяю библиотеку requests для python)
    V = requests.get("https://example.com")
    print(V)

выводится код <Response [403]>.
При попытке посмотреть содержимое контента
    V = requests.get("https://example.com")
    print(V.text)

Выводится код странички капчи. То есть сайт думает, что программа робот и не пускает ее, хотя раньше код работал. Есть у кого мысли почему так и как это обойти?
